# Azure publishing to localhost:4191

Tags: azure

I've created a simple web app for Azure that at its barebones is a calculator. Everything builds fine in VS 2010 but when I publish it there are a few issues with some of the images. I can run the site locally and they render fine.

The code is:

```
<img src="images/cal.jpg" alt="calendar" />
```

But when it's published the same line of code becomes:

```
<img src="http://localhost:4191/Source/images/cal.jpg" alt="calendar" />
```

Which does not render.

Anyone know how to preserve the same paths?

Comment: Please provide additional information: are you publishing it as a [cloud service (web role)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460772.aspx) or as a [website](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your src value needs to be absolute - assuming images is in the root directory of the app, preface images with  "/":

```
<img src="/images/cal.jpg" alt="calendar" />
```

Comment: Sergio's answer below accomplishes the same thing with the @Url.Content() helper - however, for me it is a lot easier to type "/..."

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC with Razor, this might work :

```
 <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/cal.jpg")" alt="calendar"/>
```

But you can also try this ...

```
<img src="~/images/cal.jpg" alt="calendar" />
```